# Measure disk writes

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-disk, disk-analysis

I'm looking for software to monitor/count running apps disk usage, not like Windows TaskManager and ResourcesMonitor do.

I need some kind of summary:

```
| app | disk usage (summary from start) |
```

I'm worried about my SSD.

[image: CrystalDisk result]

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for same result, here is what i found.
Directly from (unexpectedly)Microsoft: Windows Sysinternals - Process Explorer.

This software is similar to Resource Monitor but offers much more information and monitors live every single running process.

Comment: If you would not have answered it yourself, I'd just recommend the same.